# Joining tables with different amount of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to join two tables.

One table has the following structure:
ID1, ID2, Type, Birth date, sex

where ID2 is unique but the same ID1 may have two different ID2's - so two rows in this table.

What I would like to do is, add these values to another table BUT for ID1's with two ID2's I wouldn't like to have two rows but add another column like type2, birth date2, sex2 and fill these values only for ID1s which are not unique.

I tried something like this:

In a first step I already added all ID1s to the table where type=1. There are several ID1s left, where type=2. Now I would like to add these to the table like this

```
create table VB_VT_hvgruppe_LV_PRV_VPVT_HILF as 
select 
    a . *,
    c.ns5_vptypid as ns5_vptypid2,
    c.ns5_gebdat as ns5_gebdat2,
    c.ns5_sex as ns5_sex2
from
    VB_VT_hvgruppe_LV_PRV_VPVT a
        join,
    (select 
        b.ns5_vpvt_ordinal, b.ns5_vptypid, b.ns5_gebdat, b.ns5_sex
    from
        lfglende.ns5_vpvt1 b
    where
        b.ns5_vptypid = '2') as c ON a.ns5_vb_ordinal = b.ns5_vpvt_ordinal
where
    a.ns5_vb_ordinal = c.ns5_vpvt_ordinal
```

but this did not work.

Could you help me out?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data?  I think that would clarify the logic.

Comment: Debug your `select` without `create table` for start

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax:

```
VB_VT_hvgruppe_LV_PRV_VPVT a join, (select
```

shouldn't have the comma - try this:

```
create table VB_VT_hvgruppe_LV_PRV_VPVT_HILF as 
select 
    a . *,
    c.ns5_vptypid as ns5_vptypid2,
    c.ns5_gebdat as ns5_gebdat2,
    c.ns5_sex as ns5_sex2
from
    VB_VT_hvgruppe_LV_PRV_VPVT a
        join
    (select 
        b.ns5_vpvt_ordinal, b.ns5_vptypid, b.ns5_gebdat, b.ns5_sex
    from
        lfglende.ns5_vpvt1 b
    where
        b.ns5_vptypid = '2') as c ON a.ns5_vb_ordinal = b.ns5_vpvt_ordinal
where
    a.ns5_vb_ordinal = c.ns5_vpvt_ordinal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are at most two values of ID2 for any particular ID1, then you can join the table to itself, getting the lower value on the "left" and the higher value on the "right".

```
select  T1.ID1, T1.ID2, T1.Type, T1.Birthdate, T1.sex
        T2.ID2 as T2ID2, T2.Type as TYPE2, T2.Birthdate as Birthdate2, T2.sex as sex2
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2
on t1.ID1=T2.ID1 and t1.ID2<t2.ID2
```

If you don't want the nulls in the T2 values, where there's just one record, use COALESCE() on each of those fields.